# How to equally divide gradient color steps over the number of items with CSS

Tags: css, menu

A friend of mine asked me to create a menu effect whereof each menu item has a softer colour than the one before/above it. The image below describes what I would like to achieve.

[image]

To write down my goal:
I would like to have the background colour opacity to drop from 100% to 50% equally divided over the amount of menu items. If there are three it will be 100% - 75% - 50%. If there are 8 items it would be (100% - 93,75% - 87,5% etc.). This only counts towards the top-menu item, not sub level ones.

I think I know how to do this with JS (`.length()`), but I was hoping for a CSS only technique. If that's not possible than JS is the way to go.

Comment: I guess you could create some LESS or SASS mixin with `loop` to achieve that.

Comment: @Heidel: Less or SASS would not know the no. of elements that is present in the HTML. User would still have to input a fixed number and generate as many classes/nth-* selectors. JS is the best bet when the no. of elements is dynamic/unknown at compilation time.

Answer (score 2):

You can create gradient bg for "ul", set li background to transparent, border bottom and top top white.
Example:

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff,#00ff0c);
}
li {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
  border-top: 10px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>AAAA</li>
  <li>BBBB</li>
  <li>CCCC</li>
  <li>DDDD</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: That's not a bad option but would be dependent on the page background also being a solid color (and not an image or gradient).

Comment: Just take a look on my snippet :).
background: linear-gradient(#fff,#00ff0c); // no solid bg. fully editable by JS.

Comment: This would surely be an option, but not exactly what I want. I want each menu item to be a flat color instead of a gradient. If you look closely to each menu item of your suggestion, there is a slight gradient in each item. Especially visible at AAAA where the top is almost white, but the bottom of it is still light-green. Still giving +1 for the suggestion!

Comment: @SkyWookie I said page background. If the page has a image as background then the white borders will show as white areas and not show the image.

Comment: Oh and what Harry means is that if there was an image behind the menu, you wouldn't see that because the space between is covered with white, instead of transparency. Gladly there won't be an image behind the menu, so I don't see it as a problem =) - Oh I see Harry commented again, explaining it too. :)

Comment: Ok. Your example fooled me because there is no flat color on li item :).
In this case I sugges you to prepare few lines of css to style each child of ul.
Then you can put "p" to "li" and give border to "p".
//edit: not important right now :)